# Summing matrix rows excluding indices from other array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have some matrix, *W = MxN* and a long array of indices *z* with shape of *Mx1*.

Now, assume I'd like to sum up the element of each row in *W*, excluding the index appears for that row in *z*.

1-d example:

```
import numpy as np

W = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 8.0])
z = 2
np.sum(np.delete(W,z))
```

MxN example and **desired** output:

```
import numpy as np

W = np.array([[1.0,2.0,8.0], [5.0,15.0,3.0]])
z = np.array([0,2]).reshape(2,1)

# desired output
# [10. 20.]
```

I tried to use `np.delete` and `axis=1` with no success

I managed to get around it using tricks like:

```
W = np.array([[1.0,2.0,8.0], [5.0,15.0,3.0]])
z = np.array([0,2])
W[np.arange(z.shape[0]), z]=0
print(np.sum(W, axis=1))
# [10. 20.]
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get the mask to simulate `deletion` and then sum-reduce -

```
(W*(z != np.arange(W.shape[-1]))).sum(-1)
```

Sample runs -

For 2D case :

```
In [61]: W = np.array([[1.0,2.0,8.0], [5.0,15.0,3.0]])
    ...: z = np.array([0,2]).reshape(2,1)

In [62]: (W*(z != np.arange(W.shape[-1]))).sum(-1)
Out[62]: array([10., 20.])
```

Works just as well for the 1D case :

```
In [59]: W = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 8.0])
    ...: z = 2

In [60]: (W*(z != np.arange(W.shape[-1]))).sum(-1)
Out[60]: 3.0
```

---

For 2D case :

With [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for the `sum-reduction` -

```
In [53]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',W,z != np.arange(W.shape[1]))
Out[53]: array([10., 20.])
```

---

Summing and then subtracting the z-indexed values for `2D` case -

```
In [134]: W.sum(1) - np.take_along_axis(W,z,axis=1).squeeze(1)
Out[134]: array([10., 20.])
```

Extend to handle both 2D and 1D cases -

```
W.sum(-1)-np.take_along_axis(W,np.atleast_1d(z),axis=-1).squeeze(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Divaka answers are pretty good. I just give another perspective on your question. If you need masking to *ignore certain indices and doing **multiple operations*** on array, you should use numpy masked array `np.ma.array` instead of regular `np.array`. Masked array is truly for the purpose of ignore certain indices.

[document of masked array for more info](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#masking-an-entry)

```
z = np.array([0,2]).reshape(2,1)
W_ma = np.ma.array(W, mask=z == np.arange(W.shape[-1]))

In [36]: W_ma
Out[36]:
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 2.0, 8.0],
        [5.0, 15.0, --]],
  mask=[[ True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

From this `W_ma` masked array, you may do almost all operations the same as `np.array`. For `sum`

```
W_ma.sum(1)

Out[44]:
masked_array(data=[10.0, 20.0],
             mask=[False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

To turn masked array to regular array, you may use `compressed`, `filled`, or `compress_rowcols`

```
In [46]: W_ma.sum(1).compressed()
Out[46]: array([10., 20.])
```

---

**Note**: I emphasize masked array is useful when you do multiple operations on ignore indices. If you only need to do one or two operations on ignore indices, there is no point to use masked array.